# How to embed .doc and .xlsx files in a html page

Tags: html, excel, ms-word

I want to embed MSword doc files and excel files in my html page.i have tried with below code snippet to embed doc files but its not working in browser

```
<object data="http://localhost:8080/DMS/DATA/UP.docx" type="application/msword" width="775px" height="500px"></a>
```

Any help or suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: That would require an extension for each browser. Not sure any of it has some. Something like this might work better: https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Embed-Office-documents-and-PDF-files-on-a-website-4b30a00c-2023-49b2-bd15-b65e909338fc

Comment: Maybe not the answer you're looking for but you could save the doc and xls files as HTML from inside Office, then embed the results of that in a fixed-size `div`.

Comment: i need to display in .doc and .xls file format .its quite impossible to change the format everytime